# Limitation line Pivot area charts

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot, pivot-chart

I'm leasing a car, which I use my self, but also rent out for other people to use. I have 2000km I can drive each month, so I'm trying to do an area pivot graph which will track how much I use it vs how much it's rented out.

I have a table column consisting of the rented mileage and my own mileage:

```
 ___________________________________
|Date    |Rented mileage|Own mileage|
|23/03-18|           315|        117|
|07-04-18|           255|        888|
|07/04-18|           349|          0|
|13/04-18|           114|          0|
|21/04-18|           246|        113|
|28/04-18|          1253|          0|
|01/05-18|          1253|          0|
```

I've set up two filters which cummulative sums of each column which yields this Pivot area chart:

[image]

What I'm trying to do now is adding a limit line to show whether I'm above or below the average 2000km I can drive each month (only 1000km in march as I got the car in the middle of march). Something that should look like this:

[image]

I can't really figure out how to do that though. My first thought was a adding a new table with the following values and just add that to the Pivot Chart as a line.

```
 _______________________
|Date    |Allowed mileage|
|01/03-18|           1000|
|01-04-18|           2000|
|01/05-18|           2000|
|01/06-18|           2000|
|01/07-18|           2000|
|01/08-18|           2000|
|01/09-18|           2000|
|01/10-18|           2000|
|01-11-18|           2000|
|01/12-18|           2000|
|01/01-19|           2000|
|01/02-19|           2000|
|01/03-19|           1000|
```

But the Pivot Chart can't establish a relationship between the two tables, which on second thought makes sense!

I'm now looking into some sort of interpolative measure, but I can't figure out how to go about creating that.

Any input would be much appreciated! :)

PS: In case anyone is interested, I asked a related question about  [Cummulative sums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50198333/aggregated-sum-in-dax?noredirect=1#comment87426336_50198333) here.

Comment: I can probably write a measure that interpolates how you want, but I don't think the visual will allow you to add a line on top of an area chart.

Comment: Looking under "Change Chart Type" -> "Combo" I can change the measure type to line, which also drew a line when I tried to do it with the second table.

Comment: Oh, right. This is Excel, not Power BI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Date` table to use as a common axis and to relate your tables.

Once you have that table, create a new column:

```
Daily Target =
    LOOKUPVALUE( Allowed[Allowed Milage],
        Allowed[Date], EOMONTH('Date'[Date], -1) + 1 )
    / DAY( EOMONTH ( 'Date'[Date], 0 ) )
```

This looks up the target for that month and then divides by the number of days in that month to give a daily target.

Then the 3 measures you want to use are the following:

```
Cumulative Rented Milage =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Transactions[Rented Milage] ),
        FILTER ( ALL ( 'Date'[Date] ),
        'Date'[Date] <= MAX ( 'Date'[Date] ) ) )

Cumulative Own Milage =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Transactions[Own Milage] ),
        FILTER ( ALL ( 'Date'[Date] ),
        'Date'[Date] <= MAX ( 'Date'[Date] ) ) )

Cumulative Own Milage =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Date'[Daily Target] ),
        FILTER ( ALL ( 'Date'[Date] ),
        'Date'[Date] <= MAX ( 'Date'[Date] ) ) )
```

Plot these on a graph with `'Date'[Date]` as your axis and do a line & stacked area combo chart.

Comment: Thanks so much for the effort! I can't seem to get the Daily Target though.
I have three tables now, the ´Transactions´, the ´Date´ and the ´Allowed´. The ´Date´ Table, is that supposed to contain generic dates like 01-01-18, 01-02-18 etc. or should it contain the specific dates from the other table?
So far, in all the tables I made a YearMonth column in order to have a relatable column in each, and created the connection.
But the Daily Target column yields a bunch of errors.

Comment: Given that you can have multiple transactions per month, I think you want your `'Date'` table to have all of the generic days in the period you are looking at and relate the tables on the `'Date'[Date]` column, not a `YearMonth` column. I'm also assuming the `Allowed` table only has first days of the month.

Comment: Ah of course, now I have all the measures working, and yielding the same results as the old measures! 
However, the chart looks funny: [https://imgur.com/a/AIyQvGH](https://imgur.com/a/AIyQvGH)
I imagine that I should be able to do a month column in the date table, and use that as an axis, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Turns out I had the database references turned around in PowerPivot. By changing the direction of the references and changing a little bit in the pivot table relationship everything turns out nicely. Thank you very much!